# Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Cookie

Tags: java, type-mismatch

I've been trying to find a method to download files from websites within Selenium and found a solution [here](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/)

Trouble is when I copy this example and stick it into eclipse I get an error on one line reading: -

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Cookie
```

The section in question is: -

```
private BasicCookieStore mimicCookieState(Set seleniumCookieSet) {
        BasicCookieStore mimicWebDriverCookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        for (Cookie seleniumCookie : seleniumCookieSet) {    <<---This is the problem line
            BasicClientCookie duplicateCookie = new BasicClientCookie(seleniumCookie.getName(), seleniumCookie.getValue());
            duplicateCookie.setDomain(seleniumCookie.getDomain());
            duplicateCookie.setSecure(seleniumCookie.isSecure());
            duplicateCookie.setExpiryDate(seleniumCookie.getExpiry());
            duplicateCookie.setPath(seleniumCookie.getPath());
            mimicWebDriverCookieStore.addCookie(duplicateCookie);
        }
        return mimicWebDriverCookieStore;
    }
```

And is called from the section reading: -

```
LOG.info("Mimic WebDriver cookie state: " + this.mimicWebDriverCookieState);
if (this.mimicWebDriverCookieState) {
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, mimicCookieState(this.driver.manage().getCookies()));
}
```

I have no idea how to resolve this issue as I didn't write any of this code and am not that familiar, plus the original posting was well over a year ago so I'm guessing is no longer being monitored/updated.

Can anyone help me at all figuring this one out?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Try using the generic `Set<Cookie>` (or `Set<AnyOtherClass>`) rather than the raw `Set`, and most of your conversions problems will solve themselves easily. The raw types are there only for backward support, and should be avoided in any code that was written in the last 7(?) years

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you're using raw type `Set` as parameter. Change it to `Set<Cookie>`. For a raw type `Set`, the iterator you get is just `Iterator`. And it's `next()` method will give you element of type `Object`.

Comment: This gets rid of the validation warning, cheers!  I'll mark as the answer once Stackoverflow lets me! :)